# Typescript copy of object with different values. Infer partial arguments

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a more strict reducer, where it returns the actions you can call with typed arguments.

I have created the simplest possible example, removing the react specific stuff.

```js
export type TMicroReducer<T extends any[], State = any> = {
  [key: string]: (state: State, ...rest: T) => State;
};

export default function useMicroReducer<T extends any[], State = any>(
  reducers: TMicroReducer<T, State>,
  initialState?: State,
) {
  // This is not the right way to infer the args and map the keys
  const dispatch: {
    [key in keyof typeof reducers]: (...args: T) => void;
  } = {};

  return dispatch;
}

const dispatch = useMicroReducer(
  {
    add: (state, value: number, value2: string) => {
      return state + value;
    },
    subtract: (state, value: number) => {
      return state - value;
    },
  },
  0,
);
```

I can't get my dispatch function to be strongly typed.
Basically I'm expecting this input/output:

```js
// input
{
  add: (state: S, value: number, value2: string) => S,
  subtract: (state: S, value: number) => S,
}
// output
{
  add: (value: number, value2: string) => void,
  subtract: (value: number) => void 
}
```

How can I achieve this in a generic manner?

Thanks a lot,
Kasper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation has few flaws:

1. On the level of `TMicroReducer` you introduce type of every reducer arguments `T`. It means that every reducer should have only one type of arguments, but it is not true.
2. `useMicroReducer` lacks of generic for representing reducers, this not allows on proper inferring exact passed type as `reducers`

My idea for the solution was - we need to copy object which is given by `reducers` argument and from every function inside remove the first argument - state. In order to achieve that I have used utility type `Parameters` - it returns tuple of arguments, and custom utility - `Tail` which gives us tuple without first element, so exactly what we need. Thanks to composition `Tuple<Parameters>` I was able to create function types which have all the same arguments as reducers did, but without the first one.

Full implementation (changed some namings):

```
// utility type constructor - remove first element of the array/tuple
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => void) extends (head: any, ...tail: infer U) => any ? U : never;

// I removed second generic, not needed at this level
type TMicroReducers<State> = {
  [key: string]: (state: State, ...args: any[]) => State;
};

// introduced generic R to allow proper infering
export default function useMicroReducer<State, R extends TMicroReducers<State>>(
  reducers: R,
  initialState?: State,
) {
  const dispatch: {
    [Key in keyof R]: (...x: Tail<Parameters<R[Key]>>) => void
  } = {} as any; // here casting to any as we need to implement real transformation

  return dispatch;
}

const dispatch = useMicroReducer(
  {
    add: (state, value: number, value2: string) => {
      return state + value;
    },
    subtract: (state, value: number) => {
      return state - value;
    },
  },
  0,
);
```

Comment: Dude, you're a legend!! I've just uploaded the full version https://github.com/kasperpihl/use-action-reducer